# C# Unable to validate property using a custom validate attribute

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, validationattribute

I have a validation class:

```
public sealed class ValidationSet : ValidationAttribute
{
    private List<string> _set = new List<string>();
    public ValidationSet(params string[] setOfValues)
    {
        _set = setOfValues.ToList();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!(_set.Select(s => s.ToLower()).Contains(value.ToString().ToLower())))
        {
            throw new Exception("not in the set");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and here is how I use it:

```
public class Car
{
    [ValidationSet("honda", "gm")]
    public string CarMake{ get; set; }

}
```

When I instantiate the Car class by:

```
...
Car c = new Car();
c.CarMake = "ford";
...
```

Nothing will happen and if I print c.CarMake, it shows ford - the validation didn't happened.

I am just wondering what do I miss here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed the validation code actually gets called?

Comment: What are you doing to call the validation code? Attributes don't actually *do* anything on their own: they're like metadata. You have to tell some bit of code to do something with the properties marked with `ValidationSet`; nothing will magically cause it to execute on its own.

Comment: @Andrew I tried to throw exception in the attribute's constructor and it didn't happen, so I guess it is not get called; the problem is: why it is not get called and what is missing?

Comment: FWIW I tested your IsValid method and it works, if you put a breakpoint does it get hit?

Comment: @eouw0o83hf hmmm it is probably the problem but I don't know how to solve it - I thought adding the attribute will do the work when the property is set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just instantiating the class and assigning the field is not going to call IsValid, you need to use the class in a framework that examines Car, sees that it has ValidationAttribute on CarMake and will call IsValid.

In this example asp:DynamicValidator is doing the work:

[How to: Customize Data Field Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx)

Comment: I see. It works different from what I expect. Is it any other way to validate the property on the fly, so that if I do car.Make = "ford", it will throw the error? I mean another way to do it other then do it in the property's setter. thanks!

Comment: I have had great success using a framework called [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would look into FluentValidation. You can create a validator class for Car.

```
public class CarValidator : AbstractValidator<Car>
{
    public CarValidator() {
        RuleFor(m => m.CarMake).Equal("gm").Equal("honda");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var car = new Car { CarMake = "honda" };
var validator = new CarValidator();
if (validator.Validate(car).IsValid)
    // car is valid
```