# WPF validation by attributes check if property is valid

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I have a `ViewModel` in my C# WPF application which contains several properties like this one

```
public class ExecutionsCreateViewModel : ValidationViewModelBase
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Execution name is required.")]
    [StringLength(60, ErrorMessage = "Execution name is too long.")]
    public string ExecutionName { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

Thats my `ValidationViewModelBase` class

```
public abstract class ValidationViewModelBase : IDataErrorInfo
{
    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("IDataErrorInfo.Error is not supported.");
        }
    }
    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
            }
            string error = string.Empty;
            var value = GetValue(propertyName);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>(1);
            var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                value,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
                {
                    MemberName = propertyName
                },
                results);
            if (!result)
            {
                var validationResult = results.First();
                error = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
            }
            return error;
        }
    }
    private object GetValue(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        return propInfo.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

And this is my TextBox in XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ExecutionName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

Attributes are working, UI is correctly notified when property becomes invalid ("Invalid" `VisualState` is triggered).

The problem is, I don't know how to check in Create method if certain property is currently valid or not.

```
private void Create()
{
    if(/*check if property is invalid*/)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(/*property ErrorMessage*/);
        return;
    }

    //Do something with valid properties
}}
```

I've tried with `Validator.ValidateProperty` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567511/c-sharp-unable-to-validate-property-using-a-custom-validate-attribute), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127290/c-sharp-add-validation-on-a-setter-method), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187679/wpf-validator-validateproperty-on-list)) but it's not working and/or it's too messy. I was also doing tricks like

```
    try
    {
        ExecutionName = ExecutionName;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
```

But it's not working in some scenarios and does not look very professional.
Maybe `ValidateProperty` is the key, but after many "tutorials" I still doesn't know how to fill it to my needs.

Also there is second small thing. Attributes **always** validate its properties, so when user receive fresh form the `ExecutionName` will always be null thus `Required` attribute will mark it as invalid, so that control will automatically turn red. Is there a way to skip validation at initialization?

Comment: *"Is there a way to skip validation at initialization"* - yep, initialize shouldn't validate anything, e.g. by setting back-fields values directly. Properties are fine for UI and user validation, though not your viewmodel nor properties are implementing notifications.

Comment: when I bind a property to XML object attribute, the property is automatically called at initialization becouse that objects attribute seek for initial value for itself. Setting `Mode` to `OneWayToSource` is not helping. When `ValidatesOnDataErrors` is set to true, it check the validation even on initialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is, I don't know how to check in `Create` method if certain property is currently valid or not.

The same way as you do in your `ValidationViewModelBase` class, e.g.:

```
private void Create()
{
    var value = this.ExecutionName; //the property to validate
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
    var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
        value,
        new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
        {
            MemberName = "ExecutionName" //the name of the property to validate
        },
        results);

    if (!result)
    {
        var validationResult = results.First();
        MessageBox.Show(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: That's the good way to go. I've decided to use `ValidateValue` and catch the exception (if occurs), then the exception Message is an ErrorMessage I need, and this way I don't need `results`.